# How to Add and Remove xml tags of existing data inside xmltype column in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I have created the following table:
[image]

Here is 1 data row sample:

[image]

Inside this table, at column `SALPROFILE`, each column data contains a big xml data like following sample:

```
<employee>
  <id>FMCSC00015</id>
  <year>2016</year>
  <month>1</month>
  <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BASIC PAY</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>35600</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
  <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>240</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
  <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>TELEPHONE ALLOWANCE</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>800</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
  <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>HOUSE RENT DEDUCTION</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>2587.5</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
  <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>MEDICAL ALLOWANCE</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>700</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
  <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>GAS BILL</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>450</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>  
  <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>LIFE INSURANCE PREMIUM (D)</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>1718</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>  
</employee>
```

i want to Add and Remove xml tags from above sample.
For example, i want to remove

```
<PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BASIC PAY</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>35600</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
```

and i want to add

```
 <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BANK LOAN</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
  <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>23490</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
```

How can i do this.is this possible doing it without tracing the entire xml data to make it more faster.I saw that    [Appendchildxml function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions012.htm#SQLRF06201) deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your XML by adding/deleting tags with something like the following, by the means of [AppendChildXML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions005.htm) and [deleteXML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions042.htm).

In the example, the first part returns your XML with one tag more, while the second column deletes a tag that matches the condition between [...]:

```
with xmlTab(val) as (
    select xmlType('<employee>
      <id>FMCSC00015</id>
      <year>2016</year>
      <month>1</month>
      <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>BASIC PAY</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>35600</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
      <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>240</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
      <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>TELEPHONE ALLOWANCE</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>800</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
      <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>HOUSE RENT DEDUCTION</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>2587.5</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
      <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>MEDICAL ALLOWANCE</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>700</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>
      <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>GAS BILL</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>450</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>  
      <PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>LIFE INSURANCE PREMIUM (D)</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>
      <PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>1718</PAYMSTR_AMOUNT>  
    </employee>')
    from dual
    )
    select APPENDCHILDXML( val,
                           'employee',
                           XMLType('<PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>SONALI BANK LOAN-4</PAYMSTR_SALHDNM>')
                         ) as APPEND,  
           DELETEXML(val,'/employee/PAYMSTR_AMOUNT[.="1718"]') AS DEL
    from xmlTab
```

The XML to add may be dinamically built by reading data from another table, for example in this way:

```
with test as 
(
    select 'PAYMSTR_SALHDNM' tag, 'SONALI BANK LOAN-4' val from dual union all
    select 'PAYMSTR_SALHDNM' tag, 'GAS BILL' val from dual
)     
select XMLELEMENT(tag, val) from test
```

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej. i want to know, instead putting all the tags manually, i want to fetch them from table like this one: `select xmlType((select SALPROFILE from  SALARYPROFILE where EMPID = 'FMCSC00015'))` But it shows errors `wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XMLTYPE'` .So can you please help me to minimize it more.Thanks

Comment: xmlType() only casts a varchar to Xml, but the input string already has to be in XML format. You can build XML in many ways, I've put in example in my answer

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej for quick reply.Nice explanation on creating tags.Its almost very near.However, my entire xml data is inside  column `SALPROFILE from table SALARYPROFILE where EMPID = 'FMCSC00015'`.so i want to fetch them from table and add/delete on them.So can you please show me how to do it.thanks

Comment: If you have the data to add/delete already stored in a XML, I believe you only need to loop through the nodes and add/delete them to/from your given XML; we know how to add/delete; scanning nodes may be done with something like [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2518839?tstart=0), for example.