# how to group aggregate xml elements inside another parent xml tag in pl sql

Tags: xml, oracle

i have following types of xml data stored in oracle database, 
Updates

```
    <employee>
    <id>123</id>
    <year>2016</year>
    <month>1</month>
    <paymstr_salhdnm>BASIC PAY</paymstr_salhdnm>    
    <paymstr_amount>440000</paymstr_amount>    
    <paymstr_salhdnm>ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION</paymstr_salhdnm>
    <paymstr_amount>240</paymstr_amount>
    <paymstr_salhdnm>TELEPHONE ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm>
    <paymstr_amount>800</paymstr_amount>
    <paymstr_salhdnm>HOUSE RENT DEDUCTION</paymstr_salhdnm>
    <paymstr_amount>2587.5</paymstr_amount>
    <paymstr_salhdnm>MEDICAL ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm>
    <paymstr_amount>700</paymstr_amount>
    <paymstr_salhdnm>GAS BILL</paymstr_salhdnm>
    <paymstr_amount>450</paymstr_amount>
    </employee>
```

But i want them to be in following format Updates:

```
<employee>
 <id>123</id>
 <year>2016</year>
 <month>1</month>
<head>
<type>1</type>
<paymstr_salhdnm>BASIC PAY</paymstr_salhdnm>
<paymstr_amount>440000</paymstr_amount>
</head>
<head>
<type>1</type>
<paymstr_salhdnm>ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION</paymstr_salhdnm>
<paymstr_amount>240</paymstr_amount>
</head>
<head>
<type>1</type>
<paymstr_salhdnm>TELEPHONE ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm>
<paymstr_amount>800</paymstr_amount>
</head>
<head>
<type>1</type>
<paymstr_salhdnm>HOUSE RENT DEDUCTION</paymstr_salhdnm>
<paymstr_amount>2587.5</paymstr_amount>
</head>
<head>
<type>1</type>
<paymstr_salhdnm>MEDICAL ALLOWANCE</paymstr_salhdnm>
<paymstr_amount>700</paymstr_amount>
</head>
<head>
<type>1</type>
<paymstr_salhdnm>GAS BILL</paymstr_salhdnm>
<paymstr_amount>450</paymstr_amount>
</head>
</employee>
```

Here is my pl sql code Updates:

```
      BEGIN   
   xmlData:=XMLType(master_file_data);
   employee_id := xmlData.extract('/employee_id/text()').getstringval();
   select   xmlElement(  "employee",
              xmlelement("id", e.PAYMSTR_EMPID),
              xmlelement("year", e.PAYMSTR_SALYR),
              xmlelement("month", e.PAYMSTR_SALMT),
              (select  XMLAGG(                
               xmlforest(  PAYMSTR_SALHDNM, PAYMSTR_AMOUNT  )                     
                 )
               from TBL_PAYROLL_MASTER_FILE s where  s.PAYMSTR_EMPID = e.PAYMSTR_EMPID and 
                  s.PAYMSTR_SALYR = e.PAYMSTR_SALYR and s.PAYMSTR_SALMT = e.PAYMSTR_SALMT)      
                      )   AS clob into ret
    from  
       ( select distinct PAYMSTR_EMPID, PAYMSTR_SALYR, PAYMSTR_SALMT 
         from  TBL_PAYROLL_MASTER_FILE where  PAYMSTR_EMPID = employee_id ) e;

 RETURN '<result><status >success</status>'||ret.getClobval()||'</result>';
```

How can i do this.please help me with simple solution.please let me know for any further information.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
 select 
        xmlagg
             (
              xmlelement("employee",
                    xmlelement("id", e.PAYMSTR_EMPID),
                    xmlelement("year", e.PAYMSTR_SALYR),
                    xmlelement("month", e.PAYMSTR_SALMT),
                    XMLAGG(
                        xmlelement("head",
                           xmlelement("type", 1), 
                           xmlelement("paymstr_salhdnm", salhdnm), 
                           xmlelement("paymstr_amount", amount))
                        )
                       )
              )
  into ret
  FROM tbl_payroll_master_file e
 WHERE e.PAYMSTR_EMPID = employee_id 
 GROUP BY e.PAYMSTR_EMPID, e.PAYMSTR_SALYR, e.PAYMSTR_SALMT;
```

For example:

```
declare 
    ret CLOB;
begin
    with e as
    (
        select 123 as paymstr_empid, 2016 as paymstr_salyr, 1 as paymstr_salmt, 'BASIC PAY' as salhdnm, 440000 as amount from dual union all
        select 123 as paymstr_empid, 2016 as paymstr_salyr, 1 as paymstr_salmt, 'ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION' as salhdnm, 240 as amount from dual union all
        select 345 as paymstr_empid, 2016 as paymstr_salyr, 1 as paymstr_salmt, 'BASIC PAY' as salhdnm, 440000 as amount from dual union all
        select 345 as paymstr_empid, 2016 as paymstr_salyr, 1 as paymstr_salmt, 'ASSOCIATION SUBSCRIPTION' as salhdnm, 240 as amount from dual
    )
    select 
     xmlroot(
            XMLElement("result",
              XMLElement("status", 'success'),
                      XMLAGG
                         (
                          XMLElement("employee",
                                xmlelement("id", e.PAYMSTR_EMPID),
                                xmlelement("year", e.PAYMSTR_SALYR),
                                xmlelement("month", e.PAYMSTR_SALMT),
                                XMLAGG(
                                    xmlelement("head",
                                       xmlelement("type", 1), 
                                       xmlelement("paymstr_salhdnm", salhdnm), 
                                       xmlelement("paymstr_amount", amount))
                                    )
                                   )
                          )
                      ),
                  version '1.0" encoding="utf-8'
           ).getClobVal() as xml_data
    into ret
    from e
    group by e.PAYMSTR_EMPID, e.PAYMSTR_SALYR, e.PAYMSTR_SALMT;
   dbms_output.put_line(ret);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Stawros.However i thought that i could add your solution on my existing code.But it is hard for to understand the xml tag arrangements.Can you please see my latest update and suggest me any updated solution.That would be very useful for me and  other beginners.Thanks

Comment: @user5005768 Updated my answer and I hope this is enough to understand the principles.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stawros.But i want to do without `XMLElement("result",
 XMLElement("status", 'success'),` and `version '1.0" encoding="utf-8'` .I just  XMLElement("employee") as outer most tag.i was trying that but showing error  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Comment: I remove `result` and `status` from query and it works fine for me. Update my answer without them. If it doesnot work add sample of data in `with` clause or in the sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Thank you very much @Stawros. It worked correct.Thank you.BTW finally one more question to clear my concept: You already put everything inside tag `<employee>`, So Why you then  put xmlagg at outermost .Thanks again

Comment: In case if there will be a few year(PAYMSTR_SALYR) + month (PAYMSTR_SALMT) combinations for one employee (PAYMSTR_EMPID). Check `group by` expression.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stawros. i got a strange problem on this xml.when i run it from sql developer query browser ,it includes `<head>` tag fine.But when i call this pl sql function  from php , then it does Not include `<head>`.Weird why??

Comment: PHP is not in my competence, sorry. Maybe cuz  `head` is a html tag?

Comment: Thank you very much @Stawros.Your are correct. i just change `<head >` into `<head1 >` and it worked.Thanks.Also if you know something about appendChildxml alternatievs then you can help on my post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131865/how-to-add-and-remove-xml-tags-of-existing-data-inside-xmltype-column-in-oracle

Comment: Hi  @Stawros.can you please help me  on that oracle xml problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197304/how-make-this-xml-format-output-using-pl-sql